# как выровнить абсолютно-спозиционированный элемент по центру?

Tags: html, css

есть .block и .block-inner их ширина и высота не постоянны(но блок-инер меньше).
надо чтобы блок инер был по центру в родительском блоке блоке

```
.block {
 position: relative;

 width: 50%; //условно
 heigh: 20%; //условно

 background-color: blue;
}
.block-inner{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 width: 50%;

 background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У родительского блока должна быть какая-то высота. Вот эти ваши `heigh: 20%;` это не правильная запись.... На пример  min-height:300px; height:100%; Тогда что бы выровнять потомка будет достаточно написать

```css
.bl{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl"> </div>
```

Comment: высота род контейнера задана классом .col-12 и aspect-ratio: 1110 / 303; так что наверняка она не известна. именно в этом и состоит цель вопроса - узнать что делать в такой ситуации